# Support of multiple gradle catalog definitions by Github Dependabot

Tags: github, gradle, dependabot

I am inquiring about the possibility of configuring Dependabot to function with multiple libs.versions.toml files situated in distinct packages. Currently, my search has yielded a solution applicable only when there is a singular libs.versions.toml file positioned within the /gradle folder.

With a structure bellow, I do not receive any update messages from Dependabot.

I appreciate any assistance or guidance you can provide.

Thank you.

- Structure

[image]

- Dependabot yaml configuration:
- ```
  version: 2
  updates:
    - package-ecosystem: "gradle"
      directory: "/android"
      schedule:
        interval: "daily"
    - package-ecosystem: "gradle"
      directory: "/arkivanov"
      schedule:
        interval: "daily"
    - package-ecosystem: "gradle"
      directory: "/google"
      schedule:
        interval: "daily"
    - package-ecosystem: "gradle"
      directory: "/jetbrains"
      schedule:
        interval: "daily"
  ```

I want to be able to get Dependabot alerts with provided multiple gradle catalog definitions.